# Newbie help needed regarding android gyroscope

Tags: android, gyroscope

I am a newbie in Android programming and just playing around to learn more. I am trying to play with the gyroscope however I notice that when I lay the gyroscope flat on the table, the values are still moving. If I am not wrong, it is due to some drifts issues. These are my following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener  {
private SensorManager sm = null;
private Sensor mGyroscope=null;
TextView txt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mGyroscope = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt); 

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   sm.registerListener(this, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     txt.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[2]) +"\n"+  
             "Orientation Y (Pitch) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[1]) +"\n"+  
             "Orientation Z (Yaw) :"+ Float.toString(event.values[0])); 

}

}
```

I read the android api but I didnt really get what it meant. Hopefully someone could help me here.

Attached is the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

Answer (score 0):

All Android sensors return some noise values in their data. Handling this is a complex problem. You'll have to do some research to find others who've solved it.